# How to enable CORS as I dont have WebApiConfig.cs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I want to enable CORS on my controller in ASP website. The tutorials show that I have to change `WebApiConfig.cs` and add a line `config.EnableCors();`

The problem is I dont have this file. The closes I have is `RouteConfig.cs`, where do enable CORS in my project then?

I have added the following section in `web.config` file

```
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

but the Ajax calls to the API's still return

> the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

When I call the API using the browser, it works.

Answer (score 0):

CORS or Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is used for cross domain communication from the browser. The endpoint you're calling from the browser is the one to tell the browser if the request is allowed to be fulfilled and processed by the browser or not by sending Access-Control-* headers in the response.

When the browser receives the response it first checks if Access-Control-* headers exist and if the information in them matches your request, if they exist and the information in them matches the request then the browser will allow your custom client code to process the response, if headers are not there or the information in the headers do not match the request you made then the browser will block the response for any further processing.

What you have to do is to set those headers in your response.

For further reading about CORS headers: [W3C CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)